# Android Emulator Blocks sound on VMware linux host

Tags: linux, audio, emulation, vmware

I am using linux 10.04(32 bit) on VMWare. In this vm I have installed Eclipse and running an Android emulator. Sound normally works on the VM but as soon as I start the Android Emulator sound is disconnected, whit this error msg,

The default sound device cannot be opened:

A device ID has been used that is out of range for your system.

Failed to connect virtual device sound.

Can any one please tell how to enable sound while the emulator is running?

I started the emulator on a different port using the -port command still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Point to mention. Adding a android tag to the post, would help your question to be seen by someone who knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved after installing skype in to the vm!